# I can't copy and paste into the terminal in Unity 16.04 on a Chromebook

Tags: command-line, unity, chromebook, copy, paste

I have a Chromebook and have installed Unity 16.04 on the device. I cannot seem to copy and paste into the terminal as it is a laptop and does not have a mouse button which, when I looked, seemed to be required for copying and pasting.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **ctrl + insert** for copy and **shift + insert** for paste.

Answer (score 0):

If your mouse is not accessible, try copying the command with your keyboard (Control button+V) and opening your terminal by (Control+Alt+T) and pasting the same required command by (CONTROL+SHIFT+V)